# Cannot Mount Old Ubuntu Drive connected via USB: mount unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'

Tags: mount, filesystem, lvm, storage, fdisk

I am trying to mount a previous Ubuntu 20.04 boot drive (250GB M.2 NVMe SSD in a USB-C adapter) to a Ubuntu 20.04 machine at `/mnt/foo`.

However, when I try to mount the drive by doing

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sda3 /mnt/foo
```

we get the error

> mount: /mnt/foo: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'.

What is the correct way to mount the drive?

**`fdisk -l` Output:**

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 29.9 MiB, 31334400 bytes, 61200 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 54.98 MiB, 57626624 bytes, 112552 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 71.28 MiB, 74735616 bytes, 145968 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 1.88 TiB, 2048408248320 bytes, 4000797360 sectors
Disk model: Sabrent                                 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 4F5505BA-4DC5-4E54-BADB-6CA15134B2FE

Device           Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1    2048    1050623    1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2 1050624    3147775    2097152    1G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p3 3147776 4000794623 3997646848  1.9T Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv: 100 GiB, 107374182400 bytes, 209715200 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 232.91 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Disk model:                 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 4EB53D3C-C99A-4591-A7DF-12CF5846048B

Device       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sda2  1050624   3147775   2097152     1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  3147776 488394751 485246976 231.4G Linux filesystem
```

**`lvmdiskscan` Output:**

```
$ sudo lvmdiskscan
  /dev/nvme0n1   [       1.86 TiB] 
  /dev/loop0     [      29.88 MiB] 
  /dev/nvme0n1p1 [     512.00 MiB] 
  /dev/loop1     [     <54.96 MiB] 
  /dev/sda1      [     512.00 MiB] 
  /dev/nvme0n1p2 [       1.00 GiB] 
  /dev/loop2     [      71.27 MiB] 
  /dev/sda2      [       1.00 GiB] 
  /dev/nvme0n1p3 [       1.86 TiB] LVM physical volume
  /dev/sda3      [     231.38 GiB] LVM physical volume
  0 disks
  8 partitions
  0 LVM physical volume whole disks
  2 LVM physical volumes
```

**`vgs` Output:**

```
  VG            #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  ubuntu-vg       1   1   0 wz--n-   1.86t    0 
  ubuntu-vg-old   1   1   0 wz--n- 231.38g    0
```

**`vgdisplay` Output:**

```
$ sudo vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               ubuntu-vg-old
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  4
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                1
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               231.38 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              59234
  Alloc PE / Size       59234 / 231.38 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0   
  VG UUID               MUXzXK-TeF2-I723-SjZ5-I8is-s0WJ-DncRZ1
   
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               ubuntu-vg
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  6
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                1
  Open LV               1
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               1.86 TiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              487993
  Alloc PE / Size       487993 / 1.86 TiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0   
  VG UUID               l0V9Sg-oVzo-M3bs-dC7A-WVr9-pZig-CX6a9D
```

After trying random commands, the following worked:

```
sudo vgrename <UID-of-old-VG> ubuntu-vg-old
sudo vgchange -a y
sudo mount /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg--old-ubuntu--lv /mnt/foo
```

Comment: The correct way it to use lvm tools, just like the error messages states.